# Unable to center form using Tailwindcss

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm currently working on a Rails 6 application and doing a form. I want to center the form in the middle of the page. I'using Tailwindcss to style the page. But when I add the with it doesn't center if moves to the right of the page.

[image]

Here is what the form looks like:

```
<div class="max-w-full">
  <%= form_for @post do |f| %>
    <div class="md:flex md:items-center mb-6">
      <div class="md:w-1/3">
        <label class="block text-gray-500 font-bold md:text-right mb-1 md:mb-0 pr-4" for="inline-full-name">
            <%= f.label :title, 'Title:' %>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="md:w-2/3">
        <%= f.text_field :title, class: "bg-gray-200 appearance-none border-2 border-gray-200 rounded w-full py-2 px-4 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-purple-500" %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="md:flex md:items-center mb-6">
      <div class="md:w-1/3">
        <label class="block text-gray-500 font-bold md:text-right mb-1 md:mb-0 pr-4" for="inline-full-name">
            <%= f.label :description, 'Description:' %>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="md:w-2/3">
        <%= f.text_area :description, class: "bg-gray-200 appearance-none border-2 border-gray-200 rounded w-full py-2 px-4 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-purple-500" %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="md:flex md:items-center mb-6">
      <div class="md:w-1/3">
        <label class="block text-gray-500 font-bold md:text-right mb-1 md:mb-0 pr-4" for="inline-full-name">
            <%= f.label :location, 'Location:' %>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="md:w-2/3">
        <%= f.text_field :location, class: "bg-gray-200 appearance-none border-2 border-gray-200 rounded w-full py-2 px-4 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-purple-500" %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="md:flex md:items-center mb-6 upload-btn-wrapper">
      <div class="md:w-1/3">
        <label class="block text-gray-500 font-bold md:text-right mb-1 md:mb-0 pr-4" for="inline-full-name">
            <%= f.label :image, 'Image:' %>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="md:w-2/3" id="file-upload">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="fill-current text-teal-500 inline-block h-12 w-12" viewBox="0 0 22 22"><path d="M19 7v2.99s-1.99.01-2 0V7h-3s.01-1.99 0-2h3V2h2v3h3v2h-3zm-3 4V8h-3V5H5c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v12c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h12c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2v-8h-3zM5 19l3-4 2 3 3-4 4 5H5z"/><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/></svg>
        <%= f.file_field :image, as: :file %>
      </div>
    </div>

     <div class="md:flex md:items-center">
       <div class="md:w-1/3"></div>
       <div class="md:w-2/3">
         <%= f.submit "Create", class: "shadow bg-purple-500 hover:bg-purple-400 focus:shadow-outline focus:outline-none text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded" %>
       </div>
     </div>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It might help to include the compiled HTML and relevant CSS to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```html
<div class="md:flex md:items-center mb-6">
```

maybe should be

```html
<div class="md:flex md:justify-center mb-6">
```

You are in row-grid, not column so to center stuff use justify-center, not items-center (flex-col).

Answer (score 2):

Whithout h-screen class, items-center is not working so in your case 'div' that have to be centered need also this

```
<div class="md:flex md:h-screen md:items-center mb-6">
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure. You can give a try to this one. Hope it will work for you.

```
<div class="max-w-full">
      <%= form_for @post do |f| %>
        <center>
          <div class="md:flex md:items-center mb-6">
          <div class="md:w-1/3">
            <label class="block text-gray-500 font-bold md:text-right mb-1 md:mb-0 pr-4" for="inline-full-name">
                <%= f.label :title, 'Title:' %>
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="md:w-2/3">
            <%= f.text_field :title, class: "bg-gray-200 appearance-none border-2 border-gray-200 rounded w-full py-2 px-4 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-purple-500" %>
          </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="md:flex md:items-center mb-6">
          <div class="md:w-1/3">
            <label class="block text-gray-500 font-bold md:text-right mb-1 md:mb-0 pr-4" for="inline-full-name">
                <%= f.label :description, 'Description:' %>
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="md:w-2/3">
            <%= f.text_area :description, class: "bg-gray-200 appearance-none border-2 border-gray-200 rounded w-full py-2 px-4 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-purple-500" %>
          </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="md:flex md:items-center mb-6">
          <div class="md:w-1/3">
            <label class="block text-gray-500 font-bold md:text-right mb-1 md:mb-0 pr-4" for="inline-full-name">
                <%= f.label :location, 'Location:' %>
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="md:w-2/3">
            <%= f.text_field :location, class: "bg-gray-200 appearance-none border-2 border-gray-200 rounded w-full py-2 px-4 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-purple-500" %>
          </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="md:flex md:items-center mb-6 upload-btn-wrapper">
          <div class="md:w-1/3">
            <label class="block text-gray-500 font-bold md:text-right mb-1 md:mb-0 pr-4" for="inline-full-name">
                <%= f.label :image, 'Image:' %>
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="md:w-2/3" id="file-upload">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="fill-current text-teal-500 inline-block h-12 w-12" viewBox="0 0 22 22"><path d="M19 7v2.99s-1.99.01-2 0V7h-3s.01-1.99 0-2h3V2h2v3h3v2h-3zm-3 4V8h-3V5H5c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v12c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h12c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2v-8h-3zM5 19l3-4 2 3 3-4 4 5H5z"/><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/></svg>
            <%= f.file_field :image, as: :file %>
          </div>
        </div>
        </center>
    
         <div class="md:flex md:items-center">
           <div class="md:w-1/3"></div>
           <div class="md:w-2/3">
             <%= f.submit "Create", class: "shadow bg-purple-500 hover:bg-purple-400 focus:shadow-outline focus:outline-none text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded" %>
           </div>
         </div>
       <% end %>
    </div>
```

Comment: I just placed all the input blocks (divs) including the submit button inside a <center></center> tag. This tag is used to center any block. @showdev

Comment: Ok, thank you. Incidentally, note that the [`<center>` tag is obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center).

Comment: Yes I know. But you can still use it. By the way I gave this solution because i was unable to run your code as I am not familiar with rail. @showdev